# Comparing two dataframe and getting an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a two different dataframe with one similar column. I am trying to apply the conditional statement in the following data.

**df**

```
 a          b

 1          5
 2          4
 3          5.5
 4          4.2  
 5          3.1
```

**df1**

```
 a          c

 1          9
 2          3
 3          5.1
 4          4.8  
 5          3
```

I am writing the below code

```
df.loc['comparison'] = df['b'] > df1['c']
```

and get the following error:

**can only compare identically-labeled Series objects.**

Please advise how can I fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your dataframe indices (not displayed in your question) are not aligned. In addition, you are attempting to add a column incorrectly: `pd.DataFrame.loc` with one indexer refers to a row index rather than a column.

To overcome these issues, you can reindex one of your series and use `df[col]` to create a new series:

```
df['comparison'] = df['b'] > df1['c'].reindex(df.index)
```

See [Indexing and Selecting Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) to understand how to index data in a dataframe.